# How can I tell who manufactured my graphics card (as opposed to the GPU)?

Tags: linux, hardware, graphics, gpu

I'm using a graphics card on some machine to which I don't have physical access. With `lspci` I can tell its:

```
84:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
```

but which vendor/manufacturer's card is it (e.g. ASUS, EVGA, etc.)? How can I find that out (either as a root or non-root user)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As root or non-root, run `lspci -v -s 84:00.0` and look at the "Subsystem" line, that will usually give you the name of the manufacturer.

That uses the bus identifier you found already; for a more generic form,

```
lspci -v | grep -A1 VGA
```

will show the relevant information for any graphics adapter installed in your system.

Comment: Well, it looks like it works at least for the card I have now, let's hope that works generally.

Answer (score 2):

Either as root or non root user, you can run:

```
$lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1170(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

In addition, as a generic way to find a video card in any machine, this command also gives you the BUS address information to use with `lspci` as per @Stephen Kitt answer.

So in this case, it would be:

```
lspci -v -s 00:02.0
```